# How can I read from a subprocess temporarily, and exit without killing it?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two functions, A.py and B.py. A spawns a subprocess running B, and I want A to be able to get a few lines of stdout from B before exiting. After A exits, I want B to continue running until it finishes running. How can I do this?

I have written something that kinda works:
B.py

```
import os
import sys
import platform
import time
import subprocess
import tempfile


dirname = "test_dir"
# Putting data into our directory
filename = str(time.time())
with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), mode="w", encoding="utf8") as f:
  f.write("a file")

kwargs = {}
if platform.system() == "Windows":
  CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
  DETATCHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
  kwargs.update(creationflags=DETATCHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
else:
  kwargs.update(satart_new_session=True)

temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "A.py"],
                     stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=temp, **kwargs)
time.sleep(2)
temp.seek(0)
data = temp.readline()
line = data.decode("utf-8").rstrip()
print(line)
print("goodbye")
sys.exit(0)
```

and for A.py

```
import time
import socket
import sys
import os

DEFAULT_PORT = 9563

N = 10

try:
  # Building manager lock to prevent another instance from running
  lock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  lock.bind(("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT))
except OSError:
  print("A is already running")
  sys.exit(3)

filename = "log.txt"
dirname = "test_dir"
for i in range(N):
  with open(filename, "a", encoding="utf8") as f:
    num_files = len(os.listdir(dirname))
    f.write(f"idx: {i}, {time.asctime()}, {num_files} files found\n")
    print(f"Still Writing {i}", flush=True)
  time.sleep(1)
```

What I do is I open a temp file, and have A's stdout be that temp file. Then I wait a bit, and read a few lines of output from A before closing. A seems to continue even after the temp file is closed.

Is this how I should do this?  What happens to the tempfile when B ends? What happens to A's stdout if the tempfile is closed?

Comment: Description and code seem to contradict partly which is the main script and which is executed in a subprocess started by the main script.

Comment: B is the main script and A is the subprocess started by the main script